A property of compact operators
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $K(H)$ denote the space of compact operators. Prove that rang of a positive compact operator $A$ is dense in $H$ if and only if $(AK(H)A)=\{ATA:~T\in K(H)\}$ is dense in $K(H)$.
I have proved one side of the implication. If $AK(H)A$ is dense in $K(H)$, then for any unit vector $x\perp \overline{ran(A)}$ implies that the rank-one projection $P$ on $span\{x\}$ is not in the $AK(H)A$, since
$$\|ATA-P\|\geq \|(ATA-P)x\| = (1 +\|ATAx\|^2)^\frac{1}{2}, \qquad \forall~ T\in K(H),$$
a contradiction.
I need help/hint regarding the other side. Thank you in advance.

Recall the standard fact: continuous operators on $H$ with finite dimensional range are dense in $K(H)$. Since such operators are always expressible as the sum of (continuous) operators with 1-dimensional range, it is possible to conclude the following fact: a linear subspace $L \subset K(H)$ is dense provided $\overline{L}$ contains all continuous operators with 1-dimensional range.
Also note that all continuous operators with 1-dimensional range can be expressed in the form $T_{u,v}(x) = \langle x, u \rangle v$ for some $u,v \in H$. We shall use the following simple fact: if $u_n \rightarrow u$ and $v_n \rightarrow v$, then $T_{u_n, v_n} \rightarrow T_{u,v}$.
Now we prove that if $A$ is compact, normal, and has dense range, the space $L = A K(H) A$ is dense in $K(H)$. Let $u, v \in H$. We claim that operator $T_{u,v}$ can be approximated arbitrarily close by operators of the form $ATA$, where $T \in K(H)$. Indeed, let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be such that $A^*x_n \rightarrow u$ and $Ay_n \rightarrow v$ (here we need density of the range of $A$ and normality do deduce density of the range of $A^*$). It is easy to see that $A T_{x_n, y_n} A = T_{A^*x_n, Ay_n} \rightarrow T_{u,v}$. Thus, $T_{u,v} \in \overline{L}$. The density of $L$ in $K(H)$ follows due to the first paragraph.

This is wrong. $AT_{x,y}A = T_{A^\ast x,Ay}$ instead of $T_{Ax,Ay}$. The result is in fact, false. For example, on $H = \ell^2$, the operator defined by $A(e_1) = 0$ and $A(e_n) = 2^{-n}e_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$ is compact and has dense range, but $AK(H)A$ is not dense in $K(H)$, as any $ATA$ satisfies $ATA(e_1) = 0$.

The correct statement should be $A$ has dense range iff $AK(H)A^\ast$ is dense in $K(H)$, or iff $AK(H)$ is dense in $K(H)$. Instead, $AK(H)A$ being dense is equivalent to $A$ having dense range and $A$ being injective.

(Of course, if $A$ is normal, then $A$ has dense range iff $A$ is injective, so the result is true in that case. But the OP never assumed normality.)

Many thanks @DavidGao, I meant positive compact operator in which case $A^*=A$. I just corrected it.

@pmun In that case Matsmir’s answer works perfectly. If you find it satisfactory, you can accept it.

Many thanks, I am going through it now @DavidGao. I will once I am done.

@DavidGao Thank you for pointing out a mistake! I corrected the proof to work out in the case of normal $A$.
